# How to get the Spellcheck response as List<String> in SolrJ

Tags: java, json, solr, solrj

I am trying to implement auto complete using Solr's Spellcheck response.
I am able to get the response for the given query,but I am unable to get the terms suggested to a List of strings in Solrj.

**Solr response:**

```
    {
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1},
  "spellcheck":{
    "suggestions":[
      "stac",{
        "numFound":4,
        "startOffset":0,
        "endOffset":3,
        "suggestion":["stack",
          "stacking"]}]}}
```

**SolrJ Code:**

```
SolrClient solrClients=new HttpSolrClient.Builder("http://localhost:8983/solr/star/").build();
            SolrQuery sq = new SolrQuery();
            sq.setRequestHandler("/suggest");
            sq.set("spellcheck", true);
            sq.set("spellcheck.dictionary", "suggestDictionary");
            sq.set("suggest.q",query);
            sq.setQuery(query);
            QueryResponse rsp = solrClients.query(sq);
```

I am trying to get the suggested words into a List of strings,but unable to find a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly there. Once you get the QueryRespnse, you need to extract the SpellCheckResponse and then get the suggestions from there in the following way:

```
QueryResponse queryResponse = solrClients.query(sq);
SpellCheckResponse spellCheckResponse = queryResponse.getSpellCheckResponse();
List<Suggestion> suggestions = spellCheckResponse.getSuggestions();
```

it's worth mentioning that you have also the option of getting suggestions in a map as:

```
Map<String, Suggestion> suggestionsMap = spellCheckResponse.getSuggestionMap();
```

Once you have the suggestion that you want (Iterating over the list or getting the value from the map), you can get the list of alternatives using this code:

```
List<String suggestedWords> = spellCheckResponse.getAlternatives();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response.

Comment: I tried the Solr.SuggesterComponent and was able to get the sugegstions.